# How fast is left shift (<<2) compared to multiply by 2(*2) in java?

Tags: java, performance

```
int i=3;
int doubleThruShift = i<<1;
int doubleThruMul = i*2;
```

How fast is computing line 2 compared to computing line 3?
Is the performance boost worth it , if we use  left shift to multiply by 2?

Comment: JVM should detect and optimize such code, you should no worry.

Comment: While I know what you meant, the code as shown should not take *any* time, you've only produced some constants that are not even used.